# A join in HQL, how to with Criteria?

Tags: hibernate

I have a Address class type and a Employee class type. Address has a collection of Employee's.

I have in HQL,

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from Address a left join  a.employees  where a.zipcode like '%Work'" );
List<Address>addresses=query.list();
```

There are 5 Address instances, each with 5 Eemployee instances in it's collection.So we get 25 entries of pairs.

We see,

```
addresses       ArrayList<E>  (id=42)
        elementData     Object[25]  (id=59)
                [0]     Object[2]  (id=61)
                        [0]     Address  (id=66)
                        [1]     Employee  (id=67)
...
```

I have printed the first entry only.

How do you get this result with Criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Address.class);
crit.setFetchMode("employees", FetchMode.JOIN);
crit.add(Restrictions.like("zipcode", "Work", MatchMode.END));
List<Address>addresses = crit.list();
```

Comment: Then I get a list of Address (each with an initialized collection), but not a  list of Object[2].

Comment: @PredragMaric may you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602318/hibernate-myinterceptoronflushdirty-is-never-called pls?