# The onFlushDirty Hibernate Interceptor method is never called

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

**Question:** *Why `MyInterceptor#onFlushDirty` is never called?*

I extend `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean` in xml configs like

```
<bean id="myEntityManagerFactory" parent="abstractEntityManagerFactoryBean" abstract="true">
  <property name="entityInterceptor">
    <bean class="xxxx.MyInterceptor"/>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="abstractEntityManagerFactoryBean" class="xxxx.MyEntityManagerFactoryBean"/>
```

**MyEntityManagerFactoryBean**

```
public class MyEntityManagerFactoryBean extends AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean implements LoadTimeWeaverAware {
  private Interceptor entityInterceptor;

  public Interceptor getEntityInterceptor() {
    return entityInterceptor;
  }

  public void setEntityInterceptor(Interceptor interceptor) {
    entityInterceptor = interceptor;
  }
}
```

**MyInterceptor:**

```
public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    public MyInterceptor() {
        System.out.println("init"); // Works well 
    }
    // PROBLEM - is never called
    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,
                                Serializable id,
                                Object[] currentState,
                                Object[] previousState,
                                String[] propertyNames,
                                Type[] types) {

        if (entity instanceof File) {
            .....
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE: [explanation why custom dirty policy looks like not my way]**

I want update `modified` timestamp each time I change something in `Folder` entity EXCEPT `folderPosition`. In the same time `folderPosition` should be persistent and not transient (means cause entity to be dirty).

Due I use Spring Transactional and Hibernate Templates, there is some nuances:

1) I can't update modified timestamp at the end of each setter like:

```
public void setXXX(XXX xxx) {
  //PROBLEM: Hibernate templates collect object via setters, 
  //means simple get query will cause multiple 'modified' timestamp updates
  this.xxx = xxx;
  this.modified = new Date();
}
```

2) I can't call `setModified` manually, because it has about 25 fields, and `setXXX` for each field is scattered across whole app. And I have no power to make refactoring.

```
@Entity
public class Folder {

  /**
   * GOAL: Changing of each of these fields except 'folderPosition' should cause 
   * 'modified' timestamp update
   */
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private Date created;
  private Date modified;
  private Integer folderLocation;

  @PreUpdate
  public void preUpdate() {
     //PROBLEM : change modified even if only location field has been changed!
     //PROBLEM: need to know which fields have been updated!
     modified = new Date(); 
  }   
  ....
}
```

Comment: can you show custom EntityManager class which you want to populate by using this spring configuartion

Comment: @Vihar I've a little advance. But my interceptor still not work as I expect. May you look at my updated question pls?

Comment: @Vihar Do you mean I need to remove constructor now?

Comment: @Vihar the earlier error was caused by absence `getInterceptor/setInterceptor` at `MyEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Comment: Off topic, but it is always recommended to add `@Override` on complex methods. Just to be sure you're not accidentally declaring a new method because of a typo.

Comment: Your config shows `MyManagerFactoryBean` but the class name is `MyEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Comment: @geert3 that's just a typo while anonymize the code. Already corrected

Comment: @geert3 Maybe I should register interceptor inside transactionManager instead of entityManagerFactory?

Comment: did you tried to update an entity?

Comment: @user23123412 yes, of course

Answer (score 4):

You need to extend the `findDirty` method not `onFlushDirty`. Check [this tutorial](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-hibernate-dirty-checking-mechanism/) for a detail explanation with a reference to a GitHub working example.

Comment: thanks for so full disclosure! I learned a lot from it. May you look at UPDATE section of my question?

Comment: Just override findDirty, call super() and remove folderLocation from the result.

Comment: Done. For more details, check out my book, [High-Performance Java Persistence](https://leanpub.com/high-performance-java-persistence/).